# zf2 how to use 3rd party module in my own specific module (based on route)?

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, bjyauthorize

I'm developping a website by ZendFramework 2. I have 2 modules: module for administration called Administration(route defined like www.mysite.com/admin/...) et module public site called Application(route defined like www.mysite.com/...) I distinguish the 2 modules by the route.

I don't know how to distinguish the two modules based on route.

To make it clear, I have 2 questions for example:

1. I use Zfcuser for the login system for the module Administration et in `Administration/Module.php` I added the following code to the purpose that if one user doesn't have identity the layout will change to the login form.

   ```
   namespace Administration;

   use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
   use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

   class Module {
       public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
           $eventManager = $e->getApplication ()->getEventManager ();
           $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener ();
           $moduleRouteListener->attach ( $eventManager );
           $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkLoginChangeLayout'));

       }
       public function checkLoginChangeLayout(MvcEvent $e) {
       if (! $e->getApplication ()->getServiceManager ()->get ( 'zfcuser_auth_service' )->hasIdentity ()) {
           $controller = $e->getTarget ();
           $controller->layout ( 'layout/authentication.phtml' );
           }
       }

       public function getConfig() {
       return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
       }

       public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
       return array (
               'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array (
                       'namespaces' => array (
                               __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__ 
                       ) 
               ) 
           );
       }
   }
   ```

But all the 2 modules are affected by the `function checkLoginChangeLayout()`. I want to use the module ZfcUser just in the module Administration but not the module Application.
Can I do something about the Module Manager or Event Manager to solve the problem?

1. I've found a 3rd party module called BjyAuthorize which is used for ACL by "guard". When I active the module in `application.config.php` , all my 2 modules are controlled by it. But I just want to use the 3rd party module in the module Administration but not the other modules.

Answer (score 0):

your first approach is fail

because (as you found) there is another module for doing such a thing called BJYAUTHORIZE

it has a config for allowing different type of users access which controller/action/module/route/...

plz review it's documentation for more information and also there is a blog post for How to join ZFCUser and BJY together .
http://samminds.com/2013/03/zfcuser-bjyauthorize-and-doctrine-working-together/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already realized "join zfcuser and bjy together". The example in the link is just one module in the application. But my problem is I just want to use them in only one module and the other modules will not be affected.

Comment: u can allow the whole route of your 2nd module to bypass bjyauthorize gaurd